# An Orthonormal Basis for $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, orthonormal

I am currently taking a linear algebra course and we are using the textbook by Larson, 7th edition. On page 249, the text says that

> In $P_3$, with the inner product  $$\langle p,q\rangle = a_0b_0 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3$$ the standard basis $B = \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is orthonormal.

The book gives that the the magnitude (the length) of the every element in $B$ is $1$. My question is:  how did they find that?

Comment: I see now, the inner product is just that of the coefficients of the polynomials !. I think I was really confused because I thought I need to apply the inner product to the elements of the basis

Comment: @Ink I suggest you convert this comment to an answer so that the question doesn't continue to appear unanswered.

Comment: Since they are orthonormal, each one of them must have $1$ as its magnitude under that inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of an element $p$ is $\sqrt{\langle p, p \rangle}$. Apply this to each element of $B$.